# Net run rate calculation if team batting 2nd scores more runs than the target?

Tags: rules, cricket, statistics

Team A has set a target of 120 in 20 overs.
Team B hits a 4 at 119, to take the score to 123 in 17 overs.

For NRR calculation will the actual score (123) be counted or the target score (120)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Net run rate is counted by total runs scored by the team. This also includes additional runs (123-120 = 3) as well.

Have a look at the point table of [Asia Cup 2012](http://www.espncricinfo.com/asia-cup-2012/engine/series/524504.html?view=pointstable). Here it shows total runs scored by Bangladesh is 746 in 136.3 overs. Note if point table includes only groups matches. Bangladesh's final score of all three group matches is 241 + 293 + 212 = 746 runs. Which includes 3 additional runs (293-290) [scored against India](http://www.espncricinfo.com/asia-cup-2012/engine/match/535797.html) when the target was 290.

Comment: The irony of the series was the rule for qualifying in the final. India had much better run rate than Bangladesh but still India could not qualify as they lost against Bangladesh. (Team vs team win had higher priority than net run rate which was actually nonsense when each team had to play only one match against each other.)

Answer (score -1):

Yes. **hims056** is correct that Net run rate is counted by total scored runs by team.
But the final team score if the batsmen hits a boundary or Six when the scores are level will be taken as 121 if the batsmen were crossed before the ball reaches the boundary.if the batsmen have not crossed each other then it will be taken as 123.

Actually There were two incidents happened like this.

1.India Vs Pakistan 21 march 2014([**Check Here**](http://www.sportskeeda.com/cricket/india-pakistan-world-t20-score-error-net-run-rate/))
([**See Scorecard**](http://www.espncricinfo.com/world-t20/engine/match/682921.html))

2.India Vs West Indies 23 march 2014
([**Check Here**](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4319/how-the-net-run-rate-is-calculated-in-icc-world-twenty-20-2014))
([**See Scorecard**](http://www.espncricinfo.com/world-t20/engine/match/682929.html))

But As far as net run rate calculation is concerned he (**hims056**) is correct

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://sports.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://sports.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Prakash, as it is already mentioned, the issue is not with the calculation of the net run rate(this post is just discussing about that), your issue is about calculation of score in the last ball. Your edited answer too is wrong.

Comment: @SportsFan K.But in the question he also asked about calculation of score in the last ball.so only i posted answer like this.Correct me if am wrong.thanks....

Comment: @Prakash, ok cool, the OP clearly mentions that the chasing team had took the score to 123(ie, the ball went for 4). So, running between the wickets at that time is a different scenario that we're having a [separate discussion](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4319/how-is-the-net-run-rate-calculated-in-icc-world-twenty-20-2014).

Comment: @SportsFan ([See the news here too](http://www.sportskeeda.com/cricket/india-west-indies-suresh-raina-world-t20-winning-run/))