# How is the Net Run Rate calculated in ICC World Twenty 20 events?

Tags: rules, cricket, officiating, statistics, tournaments

I have some doubts regarding net run rate in the ongoing ICC world twenty 20 2014 event.It takes a while to read so please don't hesitate and give me a solution regarding this.

My doubt is that in match 12 of world twenty 20 2014(In Group Stage Last Match on march 21 2014) ([See Scorecard here](http://www.espncricinfo.com/world-t20/engine/match/682929.html)) Wesley Barresi of Netherlands hit a six when the team score was 187 while chasing Ireland score of 189, That take Netherlands score to 193.

If that is the case in match 17 between India and West Indies in match of super10 group (in ICC world twenty 20 2014 on march 23 2014) ([See Scorecard here](http://www.espncricinfo.com/world-t20/engine/match/682919.html)) while Suresh Raina (India) hit a four when the team score was 129 while chasing West Indies score of 129,That takes India Only To 130. why Only One run is added to the score in this match(match 17 on march 23 2014) while 6 runs are added to the score in match 12 on march 21 2014.

I don't understand the strategy behind this.Because if India's Score is taken as 133 then India's net run rate as of now(24 march 2014) will be 0.442(Runs Scored For 264 in 38.1 overs ) But Now it is only 0.383(Runs Scored For 261 in 38.1 overs ).As the net run rate plays an important role in the tournaments like this i am not very happy with this.

As being an Indian Fan now a days I look a lot in to net run rate as it has eliminated India in many tournaments including last ICC world twenty 20 2012.

Is There Any One who can clarify my doubts regarding the net run rate as i want to be sure of what was happening?

Comment: Hi Prakash! Welcome to Sports.SE. Take [a tour](http://sports.stackexchange.com/tour) of our site. Also visit [the help center](http://sports.stackexchange.com/help). Please don't ask multiple different questions at once. How the NRR is calculated and how to complaint to ICC it totally different question.

Comment: @hims056 k i altered it.pls give me a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the second time this issue has been happened.

Actually there is a law in cricket that if the second batting team won the match before the ball reaches the boundary, the boundary runs will not be added to the scorecard. Take a look at [this post](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2121/does-the-batsman-get-runs-on-no-ball-when-the-team-requires-only-1-run-to-win/2134#2134), that if the bowler bowls a no-ball while team require 1 run to win, then the runs conceded in that delivery will not be added to the scorecard.

There is [a quote](http://www.espncricinfo.com/world-t20/engine/match/682929.html?innings=2;page=1;view=commentary) in cricinfo about the last ball of India VS West Indies match that

> the batsmen crossed the crease before the ball reached the boundary so
>   it is scored as a single.

But, Rohit Sharma didn't crossed the crease, only Raina did it. Rohit started celebrating after seeing there was no fielder to stop the ball from reaching boundary. [The same thing was happened against Pakistan](http://www.sportskeeda.com/cricket/india-pakistan-world-t20-score-error-net-run-rate/) that the disciplined Raina reached the crease before the ball went for boundary, but Kohli didn't.

So the issue is, the batsmen reached the crease or not. There is no issue with the [calculation](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2556/how-the-net-runrate-for-each-team-is-calculated-in-ipl?rq=1) of net run-rate.

Comment: Yup. Those were errors by scorers in both matches. They just didn't care once the matches were over. And it seems the Indian team management too does not care about this as they do not complain about this. However, the NRR was calculated correctly as per the given score. ICC should have consider this.

Comment: @Sports Fan Thank you answer.I am bit relived right now.But still i don't think this rule is good one.isn't it...

Comment: @hims056 Why strange Things like this are happening in Indian matches only.

Comment: @Prakash - The rule is perfect but the umpires/referee/officials should take care about such minor matters.

Comment: @Prakash, don't worry. NRR is not a matter for a team tops the points table.

Comment: @Sports Fan That was OK.I was bit confused after seeing the scorecard today.Now it's Fine.Thank you Again..

Comment: @SportsFan it has happened in world cup final too.But they counted it a six for dhoni. ([**See the news Here**](http://www.sportskeeda.com/cricket/india-west-indies-suresh-raina-world-t20-winning-run/))