# Why was the ball hitting the spider cam not declared as a dead-ball?

Tags: rules, cricket, officiating, indian-premier-league

As per the [ICC rules](http://www.sugaltv.com/icc-announced-new-rules-for-cricket-matches/),

> If a batsman hits the ball and ball strike to spider cam then this ball
>   consider as dead ball.

But, during the IPL match between RCB and DD, the ball hit by Yuvraj Singh got strike the spider cam wire and it was not declared as a dead ball.

Though the series is a domestic one, the rule was applied earlier in the [CLT20 series 2012](http://www.espncricinfo.com/champions-league-twenty20-2012/content/story/587705.html).

The ball get strike the wire, not the camera, Is this a reason?
Or
Should anyone appeal for the dead ball?

**My question is:**

Why was the ball hitting the spider cam not declared as a dead-ball by the umpires?

Comment: What do you exactly want to know? We can't say why did umpire take that decision (even players can't). As per law it should be a dead ball.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Law 23.1 in the T20 playing conditions<sup>PDF</sup>](http://icc-live.s3.amazonaws.com/cms/media/about_docs/524ac4f092e53-05%20Standard%20T20_2013_19%2009%2013.pdf) it should have been called a dead ball but the umpires didn't give it. We can't say why the umpires didn't declare it a dead ball. Reading [the commentary from ESPNCricinfo](http://www.espncricinfo.com/indian-premier-league-2014/engine/match/729281.html?batsman=7716;innings=2;view=commentary):

> **11.3**
>   Neesham to Yuvraj Singh, FOUR, that sat up for Yuvi and he's walloped it to the square leg boundary. Neesh bowls waist-high short ball and it was the slower one as well. Comfortably dispatched. The ball seems to have caught the cables of the spider-cam and **usually it provides grounds for a dead ball, but the umpires give a little leeway**.

As umpire's decision is considered as the last decision, players can not appeal for the dead ball but they may ask for clarifications.

Comment: Why can't we ask for the reason? Can the umpires make decision without reason?

Comment: I said players can't *appeal* against them. But they can ask for the reason (i.e. clarifications). Also, the umpires may mistake sometimes.

Comment: This was not a mistake. The decision was made intentionally that the ball clearly hit the wire and went for four instead of six. that's why I'm asking the reason(ie, clarification). How the umpires had this freedom of not following the ICC rules?

Comment: @SportsFan - Sorry, I can't understand what your actual question is here.

Comment: My question is simple, as mentioned in the cricinfo commentry `usually it provides grounds for a dead ball, but the umpires give a little leeway`. Why did the umpires give it a little leeway?

Comment: @SportsFan - This should be a different question.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: @SportsFan - This situation (and the answer too) is somewhat like [this one](http://sports.stackexchange.com/a/4321/540) where the rule is correct but the officials didn't care about it.